# Is there a way to set the file pointer to a specific line?

Tags: c, file, pointers

Can I set my pointer of my file to the second line or the third line using c and if so, is it possible to do it using the rewind() function?.

Comment: How are you defining what a 'line' is? Figure that out, and you'll be able to skip to anywhere in the file by counting offsets from the end-of-line markers.

Comment: `FILE*` is not a line pointer

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, `rewind` will always set the pointer to the beginning of the file.

Look up [`fseek`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek) and [`fsetpos`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fsetpos) for setting a read/write position in a `FILE *`.

To set a position in relation to an EOL (end of line) marker, your code will have to read the data to find out when the EOL appears... (even if you use library functions, such as [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) or [`fgets`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)).

...So, no, you can't use `seek` or `fsetpos` for setting the position in relation to a line.

Answer (score 0):

These system calls do not understand the concept of a line, which is
user/application specific. So fseek() cannot do anything more than
go to a particular *byte offset* in the file. rewind() goes to the
start of the file. So there is no way to go to a line#.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Much Appreciated